# Offscreen divs doesn't work with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to capture some divs. All works fine if the div is onscreen at the time of capture. But if I happen to scroll down the page and the div is off screen at that time, then it doesn't capture the div. The canvas output is generally blank for off-screen captured divs. How can I fix this? How can I capture a div even if the div is on-screen or off-screen?

```
  var elem = document.getElementById('myElem');
     document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#content"), {
           canvas: elem,
           width: 200,
           height: 250,
           useCORS: true
       }).then(function(canvas) {
           console.log('Drew on the existing canvas');
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues capturing offscreen elements as well. It turned out that the html and body elements had overflow: hidden styles on them, causing the captured offscreen canvas to be a solid black image. Temporarily resetting the overflow style on the html and body elements during capture solved the issue. In your case, there may be other elements with overflow rules interfering in a similar way whether overflow is set to hidden or scroll.